# Why are django model classes not of type "type"?

Tags: python, django

Open a python shell on your django project root with python manage.py shell and observe the following:

```
>>> class A(object): pass #checking type of user-defined class
...
>>> type(A)
<type 'type'>
>>> class B(A): pass #checking type of child class
>>> type(B)
<type 'type'>
>>> from collections import OrderedDict #checking type of imported class
>>> type(OrderedDict)
<type 'type'>
```

Now look at this:

```
>>> from my_project.models import MyModel
>>> type(MyModel)
<class 'django.db.models.base.ModelClass'>
```

Can somebody explain what is going on here? Django models are *clearly* defined as classes in models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  pass
```

So why are they not of type "type" when they are imported? Does Django change the model class type through some black magick, or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: there is some magic called `metaclass`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949